# IIS7 SSL Only Works on Local Machine

Tags: ssl, iis-7, certificate

I have a website in IIS 7 with a self signed certificate.

I can navigate to the website on my PC that is hosting it.  If I navigate to the specific URL in the self signed certificate, I don't get any messages and everything works fine.  If I navigate to my domain (eg dev.ben.com), I get a 'Certificate Error' message but I am able to continue to the website and everything works fine.

On other PC's on my network, though, they can't get any https pages at all.  They can see my homepage using just http, but whenever they try to go to the login page, Internet Explorer tries for about a minute and then I get the generic "Internet Explorer Cannot Display this Webpage."

What am I missing?  I've tried exporting the self signed certificate and importing it on other PC's as well.

Thanks for your time,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've allowed HTTPS traffic through your local firewall.